# How to toggle class in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying in vue 3, using the object syntax to toggle a css class on click, but when doing so every item in that html block gets the class. I only want the one thats clicked to get it. How can i do so? (images is an array simply of urls that renders as its supposed to)

Code:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      images: Array,
    },

    data() {
      return {
        active: false
      }
    }
  } 
</script>

<template>
  <section class="flex gap-32 py-32 flex-row item relative">
    <div class="grid basis-2/3 gap-x-16 gap-y-20" data-grid>
      <figure v-if="images" v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" class="cursor-zoom-in">
        <img :src="image" :key="index" :class="{ itsActive: active }" @click="active = !active">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a different array which is of same length as of images, so that you can toggle any value of array using particular index which is your image index

```
data() {
  return {
    activeState: new Array(this.images.length).fill(false)
  }
}
```

Create one toggleState function to toggle the state

```
methods: {
toggleState(index) {
  this.activeState[index] = !this.activeState[index];
}
```

}

And change your class and click function  for the image like this

```
:class="{ itsActive: activeState[index] }"
@click="toggleState(index)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as intended.